# Identifying image location

Tags: 2d, apple

I found an image in one of my drives that's a screenshot of find my iphone.
I have a small feeling its of some importance but I won't know unless i know the location.

From the image, the general location is known. Bangladesh, Dhaka. I've spent the past couple of hours trying to find it by manually looking at roads to no luck.
Reverse image searching brought up nothing since it was most likely a personal photo.

Any way of pinpointing the location without needing to manually match roads?
Sorry if my question is vague or badly worded.

[image: find my iphone screenshot]

Comment: Using what GIS software?

Comment: Looked at roads via google maps, reverse image searched via tineye and google.

Comment: From the information you provide: no chance. You need coordinates or an adress.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works